# TCL:How to create a checkbutton which selects other checkbutton

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I wanted to make a master checkbutton when select it will select other checkbuttons and grey out them.
I used to set a variable for each of these buttons from master using -variable set to true for all of them but this throws error saying "invalid command name 1"

The snippet of my code looks like this.

```
checkbutton .top.l.all -text "Select ALL" -variable "select_all" -command { [set sanity_check 1] [set verilog_check 1] [set lef_check 1] [set lib_check 1][set apl_check 1] } -font TEMP_varwidth
checkbutton .top.l.g1 -text "File name and operating conds checks" -variable "sanity_check" -command "run_file_ops"
checkbutton .top.l.g2 -text "Syntax Checks for Verilog" -variable "verilog_check" -command "run_verilog_check"
checkbutton .top.l.g3 -text "Syntax Checks for LEF" -variable "lef_check" -command "run_lef_check"
checkbutton .top.l.g4 -text "Syntax Checks for .lib" -variable "lib_check" -command "run_lib_check"
checkbutton .top.l.g5 -text "Syntax Checks for APL" -variable "apl_check" -command "run_apl_check"
grid .top.l.all -row 1 -column 2 -sticky nw
grid .top.l.g1 -row 2 -column 2 -sticky nw
grid .top.l.g2 -row 3 -column 2 -sticky nw
grid .top.l.g3 -row 4 -column 2 -sticky nw
grid .top.l.g4 -row 5 -column 2 -sticky nw
grid .top.l.g5 -row 6 -column 2 -sticky nw
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of replicating all the buttons' logic in the "select all" button, just use the [`invoke`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/checkbutton.htm#M26) command to programmatically click them:

```
checkbutton .top.l.all -text "Select ALL"     \
                       -variable "select_all" \
                       -font TEMP_varwidth    \
                       -command select_all

proc select_all {} {
    foreach w {.top.l.g1 .top.l.g2 .top.l.g3 .top.l.g4 .top.l.g5} {
        $w invoke
        $w configure -state disabled
    }
}
```

That will set the state for the buttons and execute their commands.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are evaluating the commands twice. Imagine it was like this (because it's essentially how it is):

```
checkbutton .top.l.all -text "Select ALL" -variable "select_all" -command {
  [set sanity_check 1]
  [set verilog_check 1]
  [set lef_check 1]
  [set lib_check 1]
  [set apl_check 1]
} -font TEMP_varwidth
```

Do you think it would be correct? `set` evaluates first, and returns the set value `1`. Then `-command` takes the 'command' `{1 1 1 11}` which is where the error occurs. The correct way to do it is:

```
checkbutton .top.l.all -text "Select ALL" -variable "select_all" -command {
  set sanity_check 1
  set verilog_check 1
  set lef_check 1
  set lib_check 1
  set apl_check 1
} -font TEMP_varwidth
```

And if you want it on the single line, it becomes:

```
checkbutton .top.l.all -text "Select ALL" -variable "select_all" -command {set sanity_check 1; set verilog_check 1; set lef_check 1; set lib_check 1; set apl_check 1} -font TEMP_varwidth
```

---

As per comments, here's a sample to:

- Make select all check all other checkbuttons when the select all checkbutton was unchecked

  - Execute each checkbutton's command
  - Grey out each checkbutton command
- Reverse the visible changes from when select all is clicked if the select all checkbutton was checked (I shortened the widget names to be able to test them on my side).

```
checkbutton .all -text "Select ALL" -variable "select_all" -command select_all -font TEMP_varwidth

proc select_all {} {
  upvar sanity_check sa verilog_check v lef_check le lib_check li apl_check a select_all se
  if {$se == 1} {
    # First change the checkbuttons
    set sa 1
    set v 1
    set le 1
    set li 1
    set a 1
    # Execute their commands
    run_file_ops
    run_verilog_check
    run_lef_check
    run_lib_check
    run_apl_check
    # Grey them out
    .g1 configure -state disabled
    .g2 configure -state disabled
    .g3 configure -state disabled
    .g4 configure -state disabled
    .g5 configure -state disabled
  } else {
    # Change the checkbuttons
    set sa 0
    set v 0
    set le 0
    set li 0
    set a 0
    # Change them back to normal
    .g1 configure -state normal
    .g2 configure -state normal
    .g3 configure -state normal
    .g4 configure -state normal
    .g5 configure -state normal
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually i did find a method later the similar one that you mentioend for one line, thanks.
But my next doubt is even though these buttons are selected in widget , the actual command linked to these buttons are never getting executed, at least in my case.
 I mean .top.l.g1 ... to .top.l.g5, buttons.

Comment: @DanishSheikh I'm not sure I fully understand. You want the select all checkbox to also Select none?

Comment: I wanted following :
1) master button "Select_All" when selected sets all other child checkbuttons to true also execute proc linked with all child buttons (i am confused here as command to all child buttons is not getting executed when master button "Select_all" is selected).
2) I wanted to uncheck all child checkbuttons when master is unchecked.
3) Grey out all child checkbuttons when master button "Select_All" is checked.

Comment: @DanishSheikh That's quite a lot there. I would advise creating a proc to do that.

Comment: @DanishSheikh I have added a part to my answer

Comment: Thanks for your comments, i am writing a proc for same, will update the answer section once done with the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104850/discussion-between-danish-sheikh-and-jerry).

Comment: @DanishSheikh, you need to edit your question to put all your requirements there, not hidden here in comments.